# SonarQube 6.7 - New issue identification

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I migrated my SonarQube from 5.6.6 (LTS) to 6.7.1 (LTS).

In previous version I was able to list only the new issues created between the 2 last analysis from the Home of the project. In the leak period when I clicked on New code smells, the issues list displayed only these 2 issues.

In new version, on overview page of the project we can still see the number of new issues created (in the leak period) but when I click on the number of new issues (i.e. 2 new code smell) the list of issues is not filtered on new ones and all issues are displayed. (i.e. Impossible to limit the list to the 2 new code smell issue).

Did I do something wrong ?

See below screenshot of a project with my SonarQube 5.6.6 env.

url of link : http://sonar:9000/component_issues?id=my_project#resolved=false|types=CODE_SMELL|sinceLeakPeriod=true
[image]

See below screenshot with SonarQube 6.7.1 env. of the same project

url of link : http://sonardev:9000/project/issues?facetMode=effort&id=my_project&resolved=false&sinceLeakPeriod=true&types=CODE_SMELL
[image]

Comment: Could you update your question please with the URL (feel free to obfuscate as necessary) you end up at after clicking on your project's leak issues?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam url provided in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're likely impacted by the following issue:

- [SONAR-10451](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-10451) - *Incorrect filtering on "Leak Period" issues in the Issues page*

Note that the filtering on *Leak Period* definitely is toggled (left facet), however the above known issue impacts the output of that filtering.

Comment: Nope, there definitely is a fix planned for 6.7.x, in fact the _Fix Version_ field does show 6.7.3 . The comment on 7.1 simply indicates that other developments on 7.x turned up fixing the behaviour there.